# What does $wpdb->get_row return?

Tags: php, plugin-development

due to debugging and error hunting in a plugin, I have a quick question.

What does $wpdb->get_row() return in case there are no results? The documentation says:

```
(array|object|null|void) Database query result in format specified by $output or null on failure.
```

But when looking at the source code, it rather seems like it returns "null"...

A quick help would be appreciated, I always thought that it returns an empty array but I might be mistaken!

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#select-a-row): *Returns **null** if no result is found...*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the docs are correct... but to check you could do something simple like

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from $wpdb->posts where ID = '9999999'");
echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $result ); echo '</pre>';
```

Where the resulting output is

```
NULL
```